# How/why does React know that a hook isn't called inside a function component when directly calling that function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Out of curiosity I wanted to *call* a React function component directly; like a regular function. However, React complains:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

How does React *know* that? Here's the example code:

```
const T = () => {
  useEffect(() => console.log("effect"));
  return (
    <>
      <div> hello </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

I extracted the `useEffect` like so:

```
const T = (func = useEffect) => () => {
  func(() => console.log("effect"));
  return (
    <>
      <div> hello </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

And then re-triggered it via: `T()()` which doesn't work. But `T(f=>f())()` does work.

Is that true of *every* hook or is this particular to React supplied hooks only? Would creating an arbitrary custom hook (that doesn't depend on an existing React hook) also cause the same error? What is happening under the hood for React to determine this and *why must* it be an error to try and do this? Per my understanding these are simply JS *functions* that return a React Element (`React.createElement`) which themselves are just JS objects, no? What am I missing? Is there a way to force an execution other than extract every hook dependency and pass in a stubbed implementation?

Comment: I think this is a very good question, which I don't think I can answer personally. You inspired me to have a quick look at the React source code, where I did find [this error message](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js), and found it happens when the "current dispatcher" (which is tracked via something that looks a bit like a React ref) is `null`. So that must be what keeps track of whether you're inside a function component or not - but my knowledge of the source code is not good enough to understand how that works in any detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see where it's set up in [the React source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a8f971b7a669a9a6321b9f3cea820f68b2e4ac6e/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L2770). Outside of a mounted component, the standard hooks (`useEffect`, `useState` etc) are initialised to `throwInvalidHookError`, which does the obvious thing.

Within a mounted function component, [`useEffect` is set to the `mountEffect` function](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a8f971b7a669a9a6321b9f3cea820f68b2e4ac6e/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L2803) which does the expected effect-running stuff.

Custom hooks aren't treated specially (although [the standard linting rules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) will report any abuses), but a custom hook that doesn't call any of the standard hooks – either directly or indirectly – doesn't need to be a hook at all. If it does call one of the standard hooks then, obviously, the `Invalid hook call` exception will be thrown.

> *why must* it be an error to try and do this

It needs to be an error because the standard hooks have special treatment inside the React machinery. The ["rules of hooks"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) result in a consistent ordering of hooks within each component; they are enforced so that React can maintain internal state associated with hook call.

This is a design choice by the authors of React. Some limitations are put in place, it results in optimisations in the implementation.

> Per my understanding these are simply JS functions that return a React Element

Yes, components are just JS functions that return a representation of a React node tree. React then converts this node tree into HTML nodes with associated event handlers etc.

> Is there no way to do this other than extract every hook dependency and pass in a stubbed implementation?

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do here, but the short answer seems to be "correct, there is no way without restructuring the code". You can either use regular functions to call regular functions, or use hooks to call hooks (and regular functions). There's no magic to it – you can make your own function into a hook just by starting its name with `use`, then it can call other hooks, as long as it follows the rules of hooks.

#### EDIT

> I simply would like to invoke the component like so T().

It's still not clear what problem you're hoping to solve by doing that. The return value from a component is a data structure reflecting the component tree. You can see for yourself by writing a hookless component:

```js
const HelloWorld = () =>
  <div>Hello <span id="world">World</span></div>

console.log(HelloWorld());
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-germain-dk90ni?file=/src/App.js)

```json
{
  "type": "div",
  "key": null,
  "ref": null,
  "props": {
    "children": [
      "Hello ",
      {
        "type": "span",
        "key": null,
        "ref": null,
        "props": {
          "id": "world",
          "children": "World"
        },
        "_owner": null,
        "_store": {}
      }
    ]
  },
  "_owner": null,
  "_store": {}
}
```

So, it's a familiar tree structure with some extra slots for React housekeeping data.

We can explore a little further by calling `HelloWorld()` from a mounted component:

```
const App = () => {
  console.log(HelloWorld());
  return <div></div>
}
...
root.render(<App/>);
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-agnesi-6kmkk5?file=/src/App.js)

This renders an empty `<div></div>`, but the return value from `HelloWorld()` contains some new innards:

```
{
  "type": "div",
  "key": null,
  "ref": null,
  "props": { "children": ... },
  "_owner": FiberNode,
  "_store": {}
}
```

The `FiberNode` value hints at what React is doing behind the scenes – [Fiber is the algorithm that does what React does](https://blog.logrocket.com/deep-dive-react-fiber/), [`FiberNode` is an internal data structure it uses to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63834105/solving-memory-issues-what-is-a-fibernode-in-chrome-dev-tools).

What happens if we add a hook call to `HelloWorld()`?

```js
const HelloWorld = () => {
  useEffect(() => console.info("Howdy!"));
  return <div>Hello <span id="world">World</span></div>
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-chatelet-vsq3wv?file=/src/App.js)

Of course if we call this directly then we get the familiar `Invalid hook call` error, but if we call it from a mounted component ... we see `Howdy!` on the console output. Interesting ....

This works because, as you mentioned, these are all just plain old Javascript functions. Calling `useEffect()` from `HelloWorld()` from `<App/>` does the same work as calling `useEffect()` directly from `<App/>`. This is *not*, however, the same as calling `useEffect()` from `<HelloWorld/>`.

Let's try something else. What happens if we create a `<HelloWorld/>` element?

```js
const App = () =>
  {
    console.log("<HelloWorld/>", <HelloWorld/>);
    return <div/>
  }
...
render(<App/>);
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-cache-6rwph6?file=/src/App.js)

We no longer get a `Howdy!`, and the return value is different:

```
<HelloWorld/>
{
  "type": f HelloWorld() {}
  "key": null,
  "ref": null,
  "props": {},
  "_owner": FiberNode,
  "_store": {}
}
```

*Very* interesting. When the function component is referenced via JSX, *the function does not get called*. `<HelloWorld/>` is just syntactic sugar for calling `createElement(HelloWorld)`, and the function only gets called when that element is rendered.

Comparing the return values, we also see that the children are no longer visible from the outside, and the tree structure is just a single `HelloWorld` node rather than a nested `div` / `span` / text structure.

Let's try one more thing. What if we only call `HelloWorld` some of the time?

```js
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div onClick={() => setCount((c) => c + 1)}>
      Click #{count}
      <hr />
      {count <= 1 &&
        /* render HelloWorld component */
        <HelloWorld /> }
        
      { count <= 2 &&
        /* call HelloWorld function */
        console.log("HelloWorld()", HelloWorld()) }
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-fog-xjx960?file=/src/App.js)

Clicking on the `<div>` will update the `count`, and we'll call different things each time.

On first load, we see `Hello World!` rendered in the browser, and the console shows us:

```
Howdy!
Howdy!
```

`HelloWorld()` is invoked twice (which gives us the two greetings) – once from it being rendered, and once from the direct call.

Clicking to get a second render, we see:

```
Howdy!
```

We are no longer rendering `<HelloWorld/>`, so we only see the greeting from our direct call to `HelloWorld()`.

Clicking to get a third render ...

```
Rendered fewer hooks than expected.
```

Aha! We broke the rules of hooks and React complained about it. The first two times we rendered `<App/>`, the `useEffect()` hook was called, but the third time it wasn't. Hooks can't be called conditionally.

*But ... it didn't complain when we rendered `<HelloWorld/>` conditionally. That's the same function calling the same hook! This is outrageous, it's unfair, etc* Each component instance gets its own ledger for keeping track of hooks. When we call `HelloWorld()` directly, the `useEffect()` is tracked in the `App` instance. When we render `<HelloWorld/>`, the `useEffect()` is tracked in the `HelloWorld` instance. If we render `<HelloWorld/>` multiple times, each instance tracks its own `useEffect()` call.

---

Apologies for the lengthy but not-particularly-comprehensive peek behind the curtains of React function components and effects. I hope it went some way to address your open-ended "why must it be an error to try and do this?" / "what am I missing?" questions.

The really short answer is "when you put `<Foo/>` in your component tree, you're [not calling it directly](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/c1ae922f-dede-46a9-b24a-ccb3b17a5878)".

In terms of your original premise: "Out of curiosity I wanted to call a React function component directly", you found out what happens. React complains! If you have a packhorse and you remove oxygen and gravity, it doesn't work too well either.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the source code. It does point to "where" it's codified and implies that something with the dispatcher look causes a `null` which leads to this error. However, this doesn't really throw light on the various questions I put forth regarding the how, why and how may it be side-stepped if needed. It would be great if you could augment your answer to help with that.

Comment: @PhD thusly augmented

Comment: I simply would like to invoke the component like so `T()`. I understand it could be done by mocking `ReactCurrentDispater.current = { useEffect: f => f() }` but I can't get that to work.

Comment: @PhD Hope the new edit addresses all your questions and helps you understand why that's likely to lead you to heartache. At some point you're just re-writing React :-)